# Wordpress redirection from safari

Tags: php, wordpress, web, safari

have a problem with wordpress, when i try to go to my website from safari browsers it redirect me to another webpage, not mine. When i go to my webpage from PC and it's browsers, like google chrome, IE - everything is all right.  .htaccess file i haven't got.

Need help, in which file i can find a problem?

Comment: digit the url in the webpage, than try to press control + F5. This will be delete temp cache

Comment: nothing happend( i clean cache on my iphone and ipad but still have got this problem. i think that problem in webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in the theme configuration file, have download and install new theme, and everything is all right

Answer (score -1):

Do you have any plugins running that potentially redirect based on user-agent? Maybe W3 Total Cache?

Comment: i've got the following plugins: akismet, all in seo pack, login with ajax, wordpress SEO, wp customer reviews. But i had got this problem before all plugins was install. and i've got the theme named Elegant State